# Sum up numbers with KB/MB/GB/TB/PB... suffixes

Tags: linux, bash

I am struggling with figuring out a way to sum up a row of numbers.

I have the following code.

```
lshw -class disk -class storage | grep size: | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1
```

This gives me the result

```
2TB                         
2TB
2TB
2TB
2TB
2TB
```

On my other machine:

```
500GB                       
1TB
1TB
```

Is there a way to sum these up? I need to keep GB or TB

im totally fine it being said in GB's or a way that it only add these up if there are more than 2 results? 
I have multiple machines where i am supposed to run this command.
Some of them have 5 Hard Drives in them, some have only 1.

Comment: Thanks to paste sample output, my lshw is not outputing like yours

Comment: Hmm, weird. thats atleast how all my machines reacted to my command, so for me it works.

Answer (score 6):

It may be easier with the `xml` or `json` output format provided tools to parse those are available:

```
lshw -quiet -class disk -class storage -xml |
  xmlstarlet sel -t -v //size -n |
  paste -sd + - |
  bc |
  numfmt --to=si --suffix=B
```

json:

```
lshw -quiet -class disk -class storage -json |
  jq '[.children[]|.size]|add' |
  numfmt --to=si --suffix=B
```

Even if you do not have `xml`/`json` parsing tool, outputting in those formats would still be preferable as you get  an exact number of bytes to start with and so not losing information when converting from/to human readable format.

You could then revert to some heuristic-based parsing like for the default output format. With GNU `grep`:

```
lshw -quiet -class disk -class storage -json |
  grep -Po '"size" : \K\d+' |
  paste -sd + - |
  bc |
  numfmt --to=si --suffix=B
```

Add the `--round=nearest` option to GNU `numfmt` (in GNU coreutils since 8.21 (2013)) to round to  the nearest number  instead of rounding up. See also `--format=%.3f` to get more precision.

Comment: for these both it said "xmlstarlet and jq not found"

Comment: Sure, you have to install them, but it's quite reliable then

Comment: @TheSebM8, see edit for alternative if you don't have xml/json parsing tools

Comment: is xmlstarlet tool big? and how can i get it? cause if that way its better, im willing to install it :P

Comment: @TheSebM8, on a Debian-based system, you can run `aptitude search -F '%I %p' '~r native !~i (^xmlstarlet$ | ~R^xmlstarlet$)'` to show the install-size of the xmlstarlet package and any of its direct dependencies that are not currently installed. `aptitude install xmlstarlet` to install it (or `apt-get  install xmlstarlet` if you don't have aptitude).

Comment: libxml2 is often installed by default to use xmllint instead

Comment: I installed xmlstarlet. it added 2+2+2+2+2+2 up as 13TB

Comment: Any idea hwich package contains numfmt? " i installed coreutils" as i found it had it, but still dont have it on one of my machines.

Comment: @TheSebM8, remove the `|numfmt...` to see what that `13TB` is an approximation of and remove everything except the `lshw... | xmlstarlet...` to see what those 2TB were an approximation of and what numbers we're adding. Note that `numfmt` round up (12001 is 13K)

Comment: Will try. 
But why does coreutils not give me numfmt ? any clue?

Comment: @TheSebM8, possibly that's an old version of coreutils

Answer (score 2):

**`sed`** + **`numfmt`** solution:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage \
| sed -n '/size:/ s/.*(\([0-9]*.*[KMGT]\)B)/\1/p' \
| numfmt --from si | paste -sd+ - | bc | numfmt --to si --suffix B
```

---

`paste -sd+ - | bc` can be also replaced with `awk '{ sum+=$1 }END{ print sum }'`

Comment: for some reasons your command prints out only with T, there is no B
Also, this one for an example gave me 2.8TB for the last Machine i showed.

Comment: @TheSebM8, just add `--suffix B` , that's all

Comment: Edited my question. above. The calculations are abit off.