# Bash variable hold or keep value/data

Tags: linux, scripting, hard-disk, disk

Regarding this post: [Sum up numbers with KB/MB/GB/TB/PB... suffixes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434018/sum-up-numbers-with-kb-mb-gb-tb-pb-suffixes)

I have a few machines that have older Debian version on them and can't be upgraded to a newer version of Debian, which means that the `coreutils` package does not contain `numfmt`. I tried to find a another way to get it for it `(machine is Debian 7.6)`, but I am forced to use another way to get my disk size.

I'm currently using the following:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage | grep size: | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1 | sed -e 's/[^0-9]/ /g' | paste -sd+ | bc
```

I can easily get the size, but I am in need of getting GB/TB or even MB to it also.

If I use:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage | grep size: | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1
```

I get

```
160GB 
160GB
```

On my other machines I'd get for an example:

```
2TB
2TB
2TB
```

Is there a way to save the word after the numbers in a variable and later print it out?

Also, to eliminate the chance of a machine to have multiple drives with different sizes like

```
500GB
2TB
3TB
```

This way my command sadly does not work, it would give you `505.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the `lshw` command handy, so I faked some as follows:

```
   size: 4200KiB (4200KB)
   size: 420MiB (420MB)
   size: 42GiB (42GB)
   size: 4TiB (4TB)
   size: 2PiB (2PB)
```

(I found an example online and simply copied out the "size:" lines and made up some sizes).

I used awk here because once you find yourself `grep`ping and `cut`ting and `sed`ing, it's often easier to combine all that logic into `awk`.

The below awk script sets the field separators (`FS`) to open- and close-parenthesis, so that it's more natural to pull out the desired value. It also (redundantly) initializes the running total size (in Gb) to zero.

Each time awk sees an input line that matches the (simple) regular expression `size:` it begins the real work inside the braces. The value inside the parenthesis ends up in field #2, so we ask awk to match the digits in that field. We expect them to start at position 1, for some number of characters. The value is then extracted based on that length and the suffix is the remainder of the string.

We then grind through the list of possible suffixes (extend as necessary) and multiply the current size by the appropriate ratio (mentioned by Stéphane in a [comment on a currently-deleted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434018/sum-up-numbers-with-kb-mb-gb-tb-pb-suffixes#comment783674_434028) to be 1000-based units).

After all of the input has been consumed, awk prints the total size in GB.

Save the script into a file and run it like

```
lshw -class disk -class storage | awk -f /path/to/script
```

Script:

```
BEGIN {
  FS="[()]"
  sizegb=0
}

/size: / {
  match($2, "[0-9]+")
  value=substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH)
  suffix=substr($2, RLENGTH+1)
  if (suffix == "KB")
    sizegb += value / (1000*1000)
  else if (suffix == "MB")
    sizegb += value / 1000
  else if (suffix == "GB")
    sizegb += value
  else if (suffix == "TB")
    sizegb += value * 1000
  else if (suffix == "PB")
    sizegb += value * 1000 * 1000
}

END {
  printf "Total size: %.2f GB\n", sizegb
}
```

Comment: Can i put this script into my normal script also? https://pastebin.com/UpYjp7Xe .. this is my script. I used the `#fullspace` before you gave me this answer. then i tried ur method this way but yea, i need to have this script in all of my servers, which means i'd have to copy it there, extra work. better to have it in my normal bash script, can it be done?

Comment: Sure; just single quote the whole thing as a parameter to awk. Separate commands with semicolons.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of rounding?. Basically right now it shows me `1200.00GB` i would want it to simply show `1200GB`, don't need to know after coma.

Comment: The %.2f in the printf controls that; try using %d instead.